# Interference between the escape sequence to find cursor position and `stdin()` in raw mode

Tags: c, stdin, cursor-position, termios

I am writing a shell emulator in C, and put the terminal in raw mode. To get the cursor position and move using termcaps when necessary, I printed the escape sequence `\033[6n` and parsed its return.

The problem is that a high input rate (when I basically hit my keyboard), my input messes up with getting the return of the escape sequence, and `;` characters appear on my screen.

This is how I parsed the return of the escape sequence :

```
static int fillup_cursor_position(int *x, int *y)
{
    int             result;

    result = 0;
    if ((result = read_cursor()) != 27)
        return 0;
    if ((result = read_cursor()) != '[')
        return 0;
    result = read_cursor();
    while (result >= '0' && result <= '9')
    {
        *y = 10 * *y + result - '0';
        result = read_cursor();
    }
    if (result != ';')
        return (0);
    result = read_cursor();
    while (result >= '0' && result <= '9')
    {
        *x = 10 * *x + result - '0';
        result = read_cursor();
    }
    if (result != 'R')
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

This is the function read_cursor I called several times :

```
static int      read_cursor(void)
{
    char buffer[4];
    int n;

    n = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        n = read(0, &buffer, 1);
        if (n > 0)
            return buffer[0];
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

And finally this is how I began by setting the terminal and raw-mode to have a non-blocking read() :

```
static int  set_non_canonical_input(void)
{
     struct termios termios_cpy;

    if (tcgetattr(0, &termios_cpy) != 0)
        return 0;
    cfsetispeed(&termios_cpy, B50);
    cfsetospeed(&termios_cpy, B50);
    termios_cpy.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    termios_cpy.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    termios_cpy.c_lflag &= (IGNBRK);
    termios_cpy.c_lflag &= (ICANON);
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &termios_cpy) != 0)
        return 0;
    return 1;
 }
```

I tried separating those two inputs by writing on the file stream, or by trying to lock the file access with `fcntl()`, or by modifying the baud rate, all to no avail.

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this and that I am confused somewhere, but I can't seem to find.

Comment: raw mode and `fread` absolutely do not mix **at all**. Use `read(2)` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I had done so before and tried `fread()` as I thought that by writing on the file stream it would not appear on the file itself. I'll edit to reflect the version where I did not try interfering with the file stream.

Comment: Also, please stop using the parentheses around the return value - `(0)` etc; the return value expression ends at the `;`, no exceptions; the parentheses just make it harder to read your code.

Comment: Anyway; isn't it clear what you should do? Your logic is flawed, you expect the *first* character after the issuance of the command to be `27`. If it *isn't*, then you're going to need to read *more* characters, and retaining the others in the input buffer.

Comment: My bad. Modified that too.

Comment: I mean, it is unclear what it is that you're asking here? You're returning 0 too early.

Comment: (for others wondering about the protocol, details are better laid out [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078725/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-a-c-program-using-termcap-without-writing-a-c))

Comment: Thank you for guidance, as you pointed out, I needed to continue reading instead of returning 0.