# How to get cursor position in C using ANSI code

Tags: c, ansi-escape

I am trying to get cursor position from a little c program so after googling I found this ANSI code `\x1b[6n`. It should return x and y location of cursor ( if I am not wrong)
So
`printf("\x1b[6n");`
is giving me output : `;1R` 
I can't understand the output in terms of x and y location.

Edit :
Platform is Linux (xterm)

Comment: There's a lot more to getting the cursor position in C than you anticipated. Since the C standard doesn't have any concept of a mouse cursor, the answer to this question will depend on what environment and operating system you're using. If Linux/Unix/BSD with the X Window System, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44078725/3258851). Otherwise please specify.

Comment: For MS Windows, see [`GetCurPos()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: See also [How can I get the current mouse (pointer) position co-ordinates in X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3585871/3258851).

Comment: Various pages tell you about ANSI codes. Here is one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences

Comment: I know about ANSI codes but I am asking about output which is giving me headache because I am unable to understand it

Comment: I have this esc. seq. in my old code working properly, but i can't make small example :D Sorry.

Comment: Which code ? Can you post on pastebin  ?

Comment: I'll try to post an answer. In short, you need to turn off echo, and parse this output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

int
main() {
 int x = 0, y = 0;
 get_pos(&y, &x);
 printf("x:%d, y:%d\n", x, y);
 return 0;
}

int
get_pos(int *y, int *x) {

 char buf[30]={0};
 int ret, i, pow;
 char ch;

*y = 0; *x = 0;

 struct termios term, restore;

 tcgetattr(0, &term);
 tcgetattr(0, &restore);
 term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
 tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);

 write(1, "\033[6n", 4);

 for( i = 0, ch = 0; ch != 'R'; i++ )
 {
    ret = read(0, &ch, 1);
    if ( !ret ) {
       tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &restore);
       fprintf(stderr, "getpos: error reading response!\n");
       return 1;
    }
    buf[i] = ch;
    printf("buf[%d]: \t%c \t%d\n", i, ch, ch);
 }

 if (i < 2) {
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &restore);
    printf("i < 2\n");
    return(1);
 }

 for( i -= 2, pow = 1; buf[i] != ';'; i--, pow *= 10)
     *x = *x + ( buf[i] - '0' ) * pow;

 for( i-- , pow = 1; buf[i] != '['; i--, pow *= 10)
     *y = *y + ( buf[i] - '0' ) * pow;

 tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &restore);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: one question , in which case `if(i<2)` will be true in your code

Comment: I don't remember.

Comment: I mean Whats the reason or logic you thought before  writing this line `if(i<2)`

Comment: This doesn't work if there's another thread reading stdin, so how can I get position if another thread is doing fgets()?

Comment: @zhao, AlexP's answer provides a good solution for that case. Use another connection to your `tty`. However, AlexP example does not include the `ICANON` & `ECHO` removal. You will still need those.

Comment: @Aux, the first `for()` has `i -= 2`, so he probably wanted to make sure that would not blow up everything. The truth is he should be checking `i >= 0` before doing `buf[i]`. His code has very strong assumptions which if wrong will crash your software possibly badly...

Comment: I have a little question/problem with this, this solution works perfectly... until I added another program that pipes its output into my program. I also tried it with AlexP solution below, but this still did not fix it, even though I don't use stdin anymore to get the location right? (since I assume that is the problem after adding the pipe). The behaviour after piping input in the program is that "^[[7;1R" (or similar) is displayed on the screen, and my ```fgetc``` call after this method doesn't read any input anymore. Any ideas @purec maybe?

Comment: After testing it seems that setting raw mode in code might be the problem? running with ```stty raw -echo``` seems to work, but using the code in this answer to set raw mode does not with a pipe

Comment: @KoenduBuf: "Pipe"? Pipes are not terminals. What are you trying to do with a pipe?

Comment: @AlexP I mean that running ```./compiled``` prints ```Answerback = ...``` as by your solution, but running ```echo "hey" | ./compiled``` prints the right answer, but not ```Answerback = ...``` and also doesnt terminate (so I guess the read call is not getting input anymore).

On the other hand, again, running ```stty raw -echo; echo "test" | ./compiled; stty sane``` does print ```Answerback = ...``` so my current guess is that ```term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
 tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);``` doesnt work like stty raw -echo, but I don't know.. (https://wtools.io/paste-code/b4uc)

Comment: @KoenduBuf: Why does it surprise you? It is the expected behavior. **Pipes are not terminals**; pipes not being terminals, they don't have a notion of raw vs. cooked modes. When you run `··· | ./compiled`, the file descriptor 0 of `./compiled` is a pipe; the calls to `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()` will fail.

Comment: @AlexP ahhh, I did not think about the difference in file descriptors, that explains it, thanks!

Is there any way to make this work still? My goal is to pipe input into my program, which then gets parsed and displayed as a sort of animation, and then I would like a user to be able to press a key to pause the animation (for example), I only now realize that user input and the pipe would both use stdin, any way around this? The only thing I can come up with is getting data input on a different port, but that would be less user friendly (would be nice to just do ```data | myprogram```)

Comment: @KoenduBuf: If stdout is a terminal, you can use file descriptor 1. If stderr is a terminal, you can use file descriptor 2. (Use `isatty()` to find out.) If the program has a controlling terminal, that's `/dev/tty`.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem and got me a whole new understanding of file descriptors :D

Answer (score 9):

On *some* terminals, such as [DEC VT102](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) and later VTs, and on many terminal emulators, notably [XTerm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) and its many imitations, sending <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> will make the terminal respond with <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> *row* <kbd>;</kbd> *column* <kbd>R</kbd>, where *row* and *column* are decimal representations of the position of the *text* cursor.

So your terminal emulator is *not* replying with `;1R`; it is replying correctly, but the readline routines are eating <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> and the decimal digits up to <kbd>;</kbd> (and flash the screen or beep the bell, depending on configuration).

Here is a nice Bash command to illustrate:

```
out=''; \
echo $'\e[6n'; \
while read -n 1 -s -t 1; do out="$out$REPLY"; done < /dev/tty; \
echo -n "$out" | od -A x -t x1z -v
```

Running this gives:

```
$ out=''; \
> echo $'\e[6n'; \
> while read -n 1 -s -t 1; do out="$out$REPLY"; done < /dev/tty; \
> echo -n "$out" | od -A x -t x1z -v

000000 1b 5b 31 36 3b 31 52                             >.[16;1R<
000007
```

Note that the answer *does not* necessarily come on standard input: the answer comes *from the terminal* even if standard input is redirected.

At the inquirer's request, here is a small C program which partially duplicates the functionality of the scriptlet above. Note that the program does not handle setting the terminal in raw mode and back to cooked mode; this must be handled outside the program, as indicated below.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)

{
  int ttyfd = open ("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
  if (ttyfd < 0)
    {
      printf ("Cannot open /devv/tty: errno = %d, %s\r\n",
        errno, strerror (errno));
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  write (ttyfd, "\x1B[6n\n", 5);

  unsigned char answer[16];
  size_t answerlen = 0;
  while (answerlen < sizeof (answer) - 1 &&
         read (ttyfd, answer + answerlen, 1) == 1)
    if (answer [answerlen ++] == 'R') break;
  answer [answerlen] = '\0';

  printf ("Answerback = \"");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < answerlen; ++ i)
    if (answer [i] < ' ' || '~' < answer [i])
      printf ("\\x%02X", (unsigned char) answer [i]);
    else
      printf ("%c", answer [i]);
  printf ("\"\r\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Assuming this little program is `answerback.c`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra answerback.c -o answerback
$ stty raw -echo; ./answerback; stty sane

Answerback = "\x1B[24;1R"
$ _
```

Comment: I am not familiar with bash so your illustration is not helping me can you give same in C.

Comment: @Aux, added C programlet.

Comment: I doubt you have to do that loop to read from the terminal. simply reading from the terminal should best. read(tty,answer,4096);

Comment: @AlexP I added a comment to the answer above about a problem, any help would be greatly appreciated :D